# Can I create a route which redirects "/" to another folder with static HTML files in it?

Tags: .net, owin, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm using WebApi, and have a route setup for "api/{controller}/{id}". But I also have the following folder structure in the project:

```
\Static\index.html
\Static\pageY.html
```

I want the web site's users to be able to go to:

```
http://localhost/index.html
http://localhost/pageY.html
```

Is this something I should avoid doing in the first place? If no, is there a way to make such a route definition?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on OWIN, you can do this without touching the Web API routing. You should be able to use the [Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles) middleware for this. Example `Setup` class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var webApiConfig = new HttpConfiguration();

        // Your Web API routing setup here...

        app.UseWebApi(config);

        var assemblyPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        var assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyPath);
        var staticFolder = Path.Combine(exeFolder, "Static");

        app.UseStaticFiles(webFolder);
    }
}
```

This will serve static files from the `<dll folder>\Static` folder. So if your app is at `C:\MyApp`, hitting `http://localhost/index.html`, will serve `C:\MyApp\Static\index.html` as static HTML.

Comment: This did not work for me, reflection gets the temporary folder for the assemblies. Even when I hard coded the absolute path in app.UseStaticFiles(@"C:\etc") it did not work. The first parameter of "UseStaticFiles" is supposed to be the RequestPath (and can't end in "/"), not the physical path. I'm using Owin.StaticFiles v2.1.0.

Comment: Set your static content file in VS so it copies to the assembly directory.